# Auth0 React Native patch user by Management API

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, patch, auth0

I want to patch the user_metadata of a user in my Auth0 Authentication in react native but I get the following error:

> {"error": "Unauthorized", "message": "Missing authentication", "statusCode": 401}

So I am importing Auth0 in my react native:

```
import Auth0 from "react-native-auth0";

const auth0 = new Auth0({
 domain: Config.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
 clientId: Config.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
});
```

I use the constants `Config.AUTH0_DOMAIN`  and `Config.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID` from my dashboard from my application.

As a next step I execute the following code:

```js
 login = () => {
    auth0.webAuth
      .authorize({
        scope: Config.AUTHO_SCOPE,
        audience: Config.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
        device: DeviceInfo.getUniqueID(),
        prompt: "login"
      })
      .then(res => {
        auth0.auth
            .userInfo({token: res.accessToken})
            .then(data => {
              fetch(`https://<MY_AUTH_DOMAIN>/api/v2/users/${encodeURIComponent(data.sub)}`, {
                method: "PATCH",
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                  "metadata": {first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', skillLevel: 'PRO!'}
                })
              }).then(res => res.json())
                  .then(async (data) => {
                    try {
                      console.log('user stored', data);
                    } catch (e) {
                      console.log("error while user storing", e)
                    }
                  })
            })
      })
  }
```

Whereby `Config.AUTHO_SCOPE` and `Config.AUTH0_AUDIENCE` is also from my auth0's app dashboard.

Am I missing some authentication in my headers or is the Management API the wrong choice? Do I need to to this query probably from my Back-End?

Resources:

Official API Doc from the Management API: https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2?_ga=2.147997749.368915485.1617866251-2089752765.1617460658#!/Users/patch_users_by_id

Official react-native-auth0 doc: https://auth0.github.io/react-native-auth0/src_management_users.js.html

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You don't have to use fetch. Auth0's react-native API supports users.patch(). You can see my answer for how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this issue and I got it working after a little work.

First, I had to configure my project to give metadata write permission in Auth0's dashboard at Applications/Apis.

[image]

The two I added were `read:current_user` and `update:current_user_metadata`.
Then, in my authorize request, I modified both scope and audience.

`audience: 'https://<MY APP DOMAIN>/api/v2/'`

`scope: 'read:current_user update:current_user_metadata openid profile offline_access'`

Next, I got the userId by passing my authentication token to `auth.userInfo` like so.

```
auth0.auth.userInfo({token: authToken}).then((response)=>{
        return response.sub;
    })
```

Finally, I used the value returned from `response.sub` along with the authToken that I had setup with special audience and scope to patch the user, and it worked successfully. UserId is what response.sub returned.

```
auth0.users(authToken).patchUser({id: userId, metadata: newUserMetadata});
```

EDIT:

One other issue I see with your code snippet, if you want to use fetch, is you didn't put a bearer authorization token in the header. Your fetch response will probably return with a 401 error if that's the case. The code should look something like this:

```
const serverResponse = await fetch('https://<MYAPP>.auth0.com/api/v2/users/' + user.sub,{
                    headers:{
                        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
                    }
                })
```